# Anaconda Tabula INFO: To get higher rendering speed on old java 1.8 or 9 versions

Tags: java, python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, tabula

New to python and tabula. I was trying to convert an PDF File to a csv, but ran into a problem when using read_pdf. I keep getting a java error. Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
import PyPDF2    
import tabula
from tabula import read_pdf
```

*code inserting and modifying my pdf

```
df = read_pdf("test.pdf", pages=1)
```

The error I get is as follows:

Got stderr: Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO: Your current java version is: 1.8.0_25

Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO: To get higher rendering speed on old java 1.8 or 9 versions,

Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO:   update to the latest 1.8 or 9 version (>= 1.8.0_191 or >= 9.0.4),

Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO:   or

Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO:   use the option -Dsun.java2d.cmm=sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider

Apr 2, 2020 10:19:52 PM org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer suggestKCMS

INFO:   or call System.setProperty("sun.java2d.cmm", "sun.java2d.cmm.kcms.KcmsServiceProvider")

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error, is logging output from the `tabula-java` library, that is used by the `tabula` Python library.